ClusterIssuer Failed to register ACME account: secret already exists
I am trying to create a ClusterIssuer for my k3s installation.
However, when I create one, it fails with Failed to register ACME account: secrets "issuer-key" already exists.
I have tried changing the name of issuer-key to random strings, to issuer-key2, etc. It definitely does not exist before I create the ClusterIssuer.
This is the .yaml file I am using to try and set this up:
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: my-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    email: myemail@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: my-issuer-key
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: traefik

What can I do to get this to work?
